# Limit number of patients by appointment and type of exam (PHP - MYsql)

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a web system for an office where patients from home can register in the system and in this way can make an appointment for a specific type of examination.

When the patient requests an appointment, he places his personal data, and also places the type of test that is desired. I have a table in mysql called "exam type" where 5 types of exams are found with a schedule of the way the practice offers it, that is to say, each type of examination is realized in a specified interval of time daily.

Everything has gone well so far where I want to limit the number of patients that can request a day of the kind of test to be done, I have not been able to achieve it successfully.

The office only allows 20 appointments per day but for each type of examination only a maximum of 5 patients.

I would like to know, how could you limit that only 5 patients can request appointments for that type of examination daily?

I do not know how I can limit this part of the system and I would like them to help me. I am grateful to anyone who supports me in my question.

Comment: What you would need to do first is count how many appointments are booked in for that day then check if there is below 20 patients. If there is less than 20 you should then check the particular exam type and see if there is less than 5. I'm guessing you know how to code this part?

Comment: @MinistryofChaps Demonstrably, that's not what one would need to ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bookings;

CREATE TABLE bookings 
(booking_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,type INT NOT NULL
,booking_date DATE NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(user_id,booking_date)
);

INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, type, booking_date)
SELECT 1
     , 1
     , '2017-08-05'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM bookings
         WHERE booking_date = '2017-08-05'
           AND type = 1) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, type, booking_date)
SELECT 2
     , 1
     , '2017-08-05'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM bookings
         WHERE booking_date = '2017-08-05'
           AND type = 1) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, type, booking_date)
SELECT 3
     , 1
     , '2017-08-05'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM bookings
         WHERE booking_date = '2017-08-05'
           AND type = 1) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, type, booking_date)
SELECT 4
     , 1
     , '2017-08-05'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM bookings

         WHERE booking_date = '2017-08-05'
           AND type = 1) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, type, booking_date)
SELECT 5
     , 1
     , '2017-08-05'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM bookings
         WHERE booking_date = '2017-08-05'
           AND type = 1) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM bookings;
+------------+---------+------+--------------+
| booking_id | user_id | type | booking_date |
+------------+---------+------+--------------+
|          1 |       1 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          2 |       2 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          3 |       3 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          4 |       4 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          5 |       5 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
+------------+---------+------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, type, booking_date)
SELECT 6
     , 1
     , '2017-08-05'
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM bookings
         WHERE booking_date = '2017-08-05'
           AND type = 1) < 5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM bookings;
+------------+---------+------+--------------+
| booking_id | user_id | type | booking_date |
+------------+---------+------+--------------+
|          1 |       1 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          2 |       2 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          3 |       3 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          4 |       4 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
|          5 |       5 |    1 | 2017-08-05   |
+------------+---------+------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't see where your code is checking that the date has less than 20 appointments. There is 5 different exam types so if every exam type is chosen in a day there will be 25 appointments.